# Returning the value of a specific array[index] - C

Tags: arrays, c

I am very new to the C programming language, and I have, again, found myself in a bit of a predicament.
I need to find the largest and smallest values (and their respective indeces) in an array that generates random numbers. I was able to display the values on the screen but not their specific indexes. How should I proceed to have it work.
Here are my attempts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define MIN 100
#define MAX 990

int main(void) {
  int index;
  float array[SIZE];
  float largestValue, smallestValue;

  srand(time(NULL));
  
  for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {

    array[index] = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN) / 10.0;

    printf("Index [%i]: %.1f\n", index, array[index]);
    
  }

  largestValue = array[0];
  smallestValue = array[0];

  for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++){
    if (array[index] > largestValue)
      largestValue = array[index];
    if (array[index] < smallestValue)
       smallestValue = array[index];
  }

/*
  printf("This is the smallest value: [%i] %.1f\n", index, smallestValue);
  printf("This is the largest value: [%i] %.1f\n", index, largestValue);

OR

  printf("This is the smallest value: [%f] %.1f\n", array[smallestValue], smallestValue);
  printf("This is the largest value: [%f] %.1f\n", array[largestValue], largestValue);
 */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `largestValue = array[0];` `maiorValor` doesn't appear to be declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to know the indices, then simply save them along with the largest and smallest values you're already finding.

For instance:

```
int index;
float array[SIZE];
float largestValue, smallestValue;
int largestIndex, smallestIndex;
```

Then when searching for the largest and smallest values:

```
largestValue = array[0];
largestIndex = 0;
smallestValue = array[0];
smallestIndex = 0;

for (index = 1; index < SIZE; index++){ //You can start at index 1 instead of 0
    if (array[index] > largestValue){
      largestValue = array[index];
      largestIndex = index;
    }
    if (array[index] < smallestValue){
       smallestValue = array[index];
       smallestIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare two integers to save the `index` value in your last if statements. Something like this:

```
int largestValueIndex = 0, smallestValueIndex = 0;

  for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++){
    if (array[index] > largestValue){
      largestValue = array[index];
      largestValueIndex = index;
    }
    if (array[index] < smallestValue){
       smallestValue = array[index];
       smallestValueIndex = index;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps! I hope the best for you, as a fellow begginer